# Supplement 0 when digit is less 4

Tags: sql, sql-server

when digit is less 4 , then Supplement 0 before the number, how to do in sqlserver?
my sql is

```
SELECT 
  tt.Ddate as PzDate,
  cast(ltrim(RTRIM(tt.VouchClassCode)) +'-'+cast (tt.VouchNo as varchar(100))  as varchar(100))  as PzZh,
  t.Digest as Zy,
  t.Ccode as Kmbm,
  ttt.Cname as Kmname,
  t.Jfje as Jfje,
  t.Dfje as Dfje,
  tt.Bill as Zhidan,
  tt.Checker as Shenhe, 
  tt.Book as Jizhang,
  tt.VouchSource as Pzlaiy 
  FROM [TOBROS_CWT].[dbo].[Cwzz_AccVouchSub] t
  left join Cwzz_AccVouchMain tt 
  on t.VouchId = tt.VouchId
  left join Cwzz_AccCode ttt 
  on t.Ccode = ttt.Ccode
  order by t.VouchId ,tt.Ddate,tt.VouchNo
```

[image: sql picture]

please see the picture , i want to change PzZh format , 
for example "银-1" to "银-0001"
how to do , thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `CASE` expression and `RIGHT` as follows:

```
cast(ltrim(RTRIM(tt.VouchClassCode)) +'-'+
    CASE WHEN tt.VouchNo < 10000 THEN
        RIGHT('0000' + cast (tt.VouchNo as varchar(100)),4)
    ELSE
        cast (tt.VouchNo as varchar(100))
    END
as varchar(100))  as PzZh
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check length if its less than 4 and then add trailing zeros

```
cast(ltrim(RTRIM(tt.VouchClassCode)) +'-'+ 
  Case WHEN len(tt.VouchNo)< 4 Then RIGHT('0000' + cast (tt.VouchNo as varchar(100)),4)  
  Else
  cast (tt.VouchNo as varchar(100)) 

  End  as varchar(100))  as PzZh
```